# Flutter How to achieve Gaussian blur in AE?

Tags: flutter, gaussianblur

I'm using `BackdropFilter` to achieve Gaussian blur, but the effect is completely different from AE.

The picture before using Gaussian blur is like this:
[image]

My code is like this:

```dart
BackdropFilter(
  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
      sigmaX: sigma.value,
      sigmaY: sigma.value,
  ),
  child: child,
)
```

The effect is like this:
[image]

But the effect of AE is like this:

[image]

The effect of AE looks blurrier and `BackdropFilter` is implemented more like frosted glass. How can I achieve the effect of AE? I have used `BoxShadow`, but it can only do shadows for the surroundings, not the overall look more blurred

I've tried the opacity of the image, and the sigma, but nothing works

```dart
final Animation<double> opacity = TweenSequence<double>(
  <TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(0.0),
      weight: 20,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0.0,
        end: 0.2,
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
      weight: 36,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(0.2),
      weight: 4,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0.2,
        end: 0.06,
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
      weight: 4,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: ConstantTween<double>(0.06),
      weight: 12,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(
        begin: 0.06,
        end: 0.12,
      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
      weight: 24,
    ),
  ],
  ).animate(animationController);

  
final Animation<double> sigma = TweenSequence<double>(
<TweenSequenceItem<double>>[
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: ConstantTween<double>(80),
    weight: 20,
  ),
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: Tween<double>(
      begin: 80,
      end: 50,
    ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
    weight: 36,
  ),
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: ConstantTween<double>(50),
    weight: 8,
  ),
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: Tween<double>(
      begin: 50,
      end: 20,
    ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear)),
    weight: 12,
  ),
  TweenSequenceItem<double>(
    tween: ConstantTween<double>(20),
    weight: 24,
  ),
],
).animate(animationController);
```

Comment: have you tried fiddeling with the opacity of the image and also can you share your sigma values? have you tried various sigma values or not?

Comment: @RisheekMittal Yes, I've tried opacity and sigma, but neither works.

Comment: Can you provide complete code? or just sigma values and what is that child

Comment: My updated sigma values are: 20, 50, 80

Comment: I think the Gaussian blur achieved by AE has a shadow effect, but if I actively add shadows, although the surrounding effect is achieved, the middle part is still not blurred enough, more like a glass effect.

Comment: @RisheekMittal i have updated

Comment: Yeah wait a moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249853/discussion-between-risheek-mittal-and-nullable).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and achieved pretty much the same thing myself by fiddling with opacity , sigma  and using Stack, try this if this is what you want:

```
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Opacity(
            opacity: 0.5,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/blur.png',
              width: 300,
            ),
          ),
          BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
              )),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Your code is very similar to mine, but it doesn't achieve what I want